# Scale UWP Application to all phone sizes

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager

So I'm building UWP Application that will mainly target phones, but since it can be run on PC and Tablets I used VisualStateManager to correct the layout for bigger screens.
Now Phones also have different screen sizes and I'm looking for a way to simply scale all the components in my page without using Visual state for every single phone and screen resolution out there, or alternatively Using the state manager but without having to re position every single element for every single screen size(between 5" and 6" phones its easy since you can see preview of changes in VS 2015 but for smaller phones its pretty annoying).
here is a sample page from my App:

```
    <Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/start-01.jpg"/>
        </Canvas.Background>
        <RelativePanel x:Name="relativePanel"  Canvas.Left="-3" Height="612" Canvas.Top="10" >

            <Image x:Name="play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="83,271,-3,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="play_Tapped"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="playTB" Height="36" Margin="130,265,69.333,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="RACE" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="364" Tapped="play_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
            <Image x:Name="highscoresBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="83,337,-3,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="highscoresBT_Tapped"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="highscoreTB" Height="36" Margin="85,337,76,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="HIGHSCORES" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="194" Tapped="highscoresBT_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
            <Image x:Name="storeBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="83,403,-3,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="storeBT_Tapped"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="storeTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="124,397,-108,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="STORE" Width="151" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="364" Tapped="storeBT_Tapped"/>
            <Image x:Name="helpBut" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="144,522,-3,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Source="Assets/helpBut-01.png" Tapped="helpBut_Tapped"/>
            <Image x:Name="coinsBG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="295,0,-3,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Source="Assets/comp bar-01.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image x:Name="coinsIC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="14" Source="Assets/coins-01.png" Margin="329,1,-3,0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="coinsOwnedTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="303,2,-3,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="21" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257"/>
            <Image x:Name="scoreBG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="13,0,-3,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Source="Assets/comp bar-01.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="scoreNameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="14,2,-3,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Score: " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="scoreTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="62,2,-3,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257"/>
            <Image x:Name="feedbackBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="83,469,-3,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="feedback_Tapped"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="feedbackTB" Height="36" Margin="96,463,60.667,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SUPPORT" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="feedback_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" TextAlignment="Center" CharacterSpacing="200"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

So basiclly I need a way to scale and re position all the elements according to the Grid/Canvas/Relative panel size (They are not really all needed for this page it was just some kind of trials).

Maybe a programmatic way not necessarily altering the XAML code.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get what I was looking for with the help of a ViewBox that scales my App automatically to fit screen size:

```
    <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" >
    <Grid x:Name="canvas" >
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/start-01.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Image x:Name="play" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,281,0,325" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="play_Tapped"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="playTB" Height="34" Margin="125,276,90,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="RACE" FontSize="30" CharacterSpacing="364" Tapped="play_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode"  VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
        <Image x:Name="highscoresBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="78,335,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="highscoresBT_Tapped"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="highscoreTB" Height="34" Margin="88,335,82,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="HIGHSCORES" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="100" Tapped="highscoresBT_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
        <Image x:Name="storeBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="78,398,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="storeBT_Tapped"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="storeTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="111,392,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="STORE" Width="151" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="364" Tapped="storeBT_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="helpBut" Height="96" Margin="115,511,122,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Assets/helpBut-01.png" Tapped="helpBut_Tapped" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
        <Image x:Name="coinsBG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="294,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Source="Assets/comp bar-01.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image x:Name="coinsIC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="14" Source="Assets/coins-01.png" Margin="328,13,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="coinsOwnedTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="302,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="21" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257"/>
        <Image x:Name="scoreBG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Source="Assets/comp bar-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="12,12,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="scoreNameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="13,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Score: " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="scoreTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="61,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
        <Image x:Name="feedbackBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="78,461,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="feedback_Tapped"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="feedbackTB" Height="34" Margin="91,455,98,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SUPPORT" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="feedback_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" TextAlignment="Center" CharacterSpacing="200"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

This is what worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app to be scalable/reactive, you really should avoid using the Canvas to layout visual elements. Also, when you *are* using Canvas, you should use the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties to position elements, not the Margin property.

Anyway, the following XAML will provide a scalable layout, similar to your canvas layout but natively resizable to any display. Unfortunately, as I don't have all your assets I can't verify that it exactly matches but have taken some educated guesses about what you're trying to do:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10">
        <Image x:Name="scoreBG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Assets/comp bar-01.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="scoreNameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Score: " VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
        <Image x:Name="helpBut" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Assets/helpBut-01.png" Tapped="helpBut_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="coinsBG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Assets/comp bar-01.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image x:Name="coinsIC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Assets/coins-01.png"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="coinsOwnedTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="120" VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontSize="10" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <Image x:Name="play" Height="36" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="play_Tapped"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="playTB" Height="36" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="RACE" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="364" Tapped="play_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <Image x:Name="highscoresBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="highscoresBT_Tapped"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="highscoreTB" Height="36" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="HIGHSCORES" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="194" Tapped="highscoresBT_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock x:Name="storeTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="STORE" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="364" Tapped="storeBT_Tapped"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <Image x:Name="feedbackBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="feedback_Tapped"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="feedbackTB" Height="36" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SUPPORT" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="feedback_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" TextAlignment="Center" CharacterSpacing="200"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Note that, in most places, I have removed margins and specified width/height properties as these should be left to auto-size based on the display/DPI/locale.

Hope it helps.

Comment: well your attempt helped me understand some stuff so thanks for that.
although what I looked for couldn't be achieved by this I answered My question and found that the ViewBox does the job of scaling without the need to adjust all the pages that I had which many of them Had to have a canvas control in them and couldn't be altered that easily to scale using your method.